# Is it possible to have the dropbox api actually show the user, in the website, downloadable links to folders and files? or is this not possible?

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

Is it possible to have the dropbox api actually show the user, in the website, downloadable links to folders and files? or is this not possible?

I would like to use the dropbox api to show the user a list of the folders and files and they can download the files to their computer.

Comment: have you tried to prototype something?  Are you running into specific problems?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using a combination of the metadata and media api methods. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media

You would get the data with metadata then use the media to get the download urls.